# EmberJS-Using index routes to overwrite parent template

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have the below route structure.

```
App.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('projects', function() {
        this.resource('listings', {path: '/:project_id/listings'}, function() {
            this.route('listing', {path: '/:property_code'});   
        });
    });    
});
```

I replicated this structure and created a fiddle.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aqHnt/6/

I hope the router is self-explanatory. I have a bunch of `projects` which each have a bunch of `listings` and each `listing` will have some additional details. Because these are nested resources, each child resource renders in to the `{{outlet}}` of it's parent template.

What I need is to entirely overwrite the parent template and as per a suggestion in a different post, I'm using the resources `index` route to achieve this.

So If you click on a project, the entire projects template will be replaced with the listings template. It's all good up to this point but I can't seem to achieve the same with listings. When I click on a listing, I want the entire listings template to be replaced by listing details. Can someone point out what am I doing wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible solution: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/78SW5/).

You were missing the `listings` template besides the `listings/index` one, as well as the route `ListingsIndex`. This way you replicate the same pattern you use at `application` level.

You could also consider using [renderTemplate](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/rendering-a-template/) to specify in which `outlet` you need to render a given template.

Hope it helps!